# Transform Typescript class with getters and underscored private properties to Object

Tags: typescript, class

I have the following problem:

Given typescript classes:

```
class OtherClass {
   private _c: number;

   get c(): number {
       return this._c;
   }
}

class SomeClass {

   private _a: number;
   private _b: OtherClass;

   get a(): number {
       return this._a;
   };

   get b(): OtherClass{
       return this._b;
   };
}
```

Now i have an instance of class SomeClass, lets call it scInstance.

What i want to do is to transform this instance to an object.

Something like this:

```
const scObject = {...scInstance};
```

The problem is that the object only has the underscored private properties:

```
scObject = {
   _a: 1,
   _b: {
     _c: 4
   }
}
```

but i want an object that looks like this:

```
scObject = {
   a: 1,
   b: {
     c: 4
   }
}
```

I cant modify the definition of SomeClass, so my question is, is there any elegant way to transform this class to an object without these underscored properties?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`private` here is just a hint for typescript, it's not really private in the compiled javascript.

This typescript:

```
class OtherClass {
   private _c: number;

   get c(): number {
       return this._c;
   }
}
```

Compiles to this javascript

```
class OtherClass {
    get c() {
        return this._c;
    }
}
```

What this means is that your class is just a normal class with properties that happen to start with an underscore.

If this isn't behaviour you want, you'll have to make a custom encoder function that does do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

I was afraid that there is no elegant solution for this. Here is my current solution in case someone has the same problem.

```
const mapKeysDeep = (obj, cb) => _.mapValues(
            _.mapKeys(obj, cb),
            val => (_.isObject(val) ? mapKeysDeep(val, cb) : val),
);
const scObject = scInstance.map(det => {
            return mapKeysDeep(det, (value, key) => {
                return _.replace(key, "_", "");
            });
});
```